# What is the path for form elements which are ajax-enabled

Tags: ajax, quiz

I am working on the quiz module.
I have to modify the form `node/add/multichoice` by hiding some of the form elements in it.
With the help of krumo function of devel module, I am able to find the correct form elements and set `['#access']` to `FALSE` in order to hide them.
All this is done in a custom module using the `hook_form_alter()`.

But the problem is that I have to hide advanced fieldset under alternatives.
The path for form element for advanced fieldset is thus like below :
`$form['alternatives'][0]['advanced']`
`$form['alternatives'][1]['advanced']`
But there is an option of add more alternatives.
What is the path for form elements which are ajax enabled.

Comment: You have to loop through `$form['alternatives']`:
`foreach ($form['alternatives'] as $delta => &$alternative) {
  $alternative['#access'] = FALSE;
}`

Comment: thankyou so much. Let me try and get back to you.regards.

Comment: Probably best to loop through `element_children($form['alternatives'])`, you're likely to run into problems otherwise

Comment: it is throwing errors. please look into it.

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset '#access' in znew_form_alter() (line 24 of C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite\sites\all\modules\znew\znew.module).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#access' in znew_form_alter() (line 24 of C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite\sites\all\modules\znew\znew.module).
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in znew_form_alter() (line 24 of C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite\sites\all\modules\znew\znew.module).

Comment: @TulikaSharma follow Clive's advice and use `element_children` instead. That should avoid this issue you're having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (element_children($form['alternatives']) as $delta) {
  $form['alternatives'][$delta]['advanced']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

Something like this.